# передача файла в List

Tags: java, файлы, list

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]есть файл "students.txt" в папке src

надо загрузить его в List
и вывести на консоль

```
public class FromFileList {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> students = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("students.txt"),
                                               StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    for(String student: students){
      System.out.println(student);
    }
  }
}
```

что я не так делаю

Comment: Файл в вашем случае должен быть в корне проекта, а не в src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю вам нужно добавить файл в папку ресурсов и все у вас заработает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Path path = Paths.get("resources", "students.txt");

        List<String> students = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        students.forEach(System.out::println);

    }

}
```

Comment: не ошибку выдаёт всё одно что-то не так

Comment: ааа...так а что у вас написано в файле students.txt? Эта ошибка говорит вам о том, что кодировки файла и способа считывания не совпадают

Comment: Вам просто нужно понять, какую кодировку использовать. Можете путем перебора.

Comment: в файле список в один столбец на русском. как понять какую кодировку мне где найти то что перебирать?

Comment: с ISO_8859_1 всё работает но выдаёт кракозябри на консоль типа: Àâãóñòà. и чего делать теперь?

Comment: либо кодировка не совсем подходящая(если windos oc, то возможно "windows-1251") или кодировка консоли не соответсвует

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94634/discussion-between-padla-and-andrii-torzhkov).